# How can I display last 3 character in text box field with asterisk (password field)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm currently working for a project in aspx C#, I want to user to type some text (e.g phone number) in text box, while typing in the text field should shows asterisk sign (*) and last 3 digit of the phone number, example : *********810 
Any one can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. This can be done using some JavaScript. Start coding and add the result to the question. Explain your specific problem. Refer the [ask] link for more details how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this requirement by `javascript` using `regex` to replace last 3 digits at event `onkeyup` of input tag and need a hidden field to keep original value.

```
function mask(){
   //console.log($("#phone").val());
   $("#phone").val($("#phone").val().replace(/\d(?=\d{3})/g, "*"));
}
```

```js
function mask(){
   //console.log($("#phone").val());
   $("#phone").val($("#phone").val().replace(/\d(?=\d{3})/g, "*"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone" onkeyup="mask()" />
```